# Do you know how to rotate 3D model to face camera using ARKIT?

Tags: ios, object, 3d, augmented-reality, arkit

I have 2 questions in mind to place 3D object.

1. If a 3D object(for example Car) created to face door side of the car as camera's front face, how can I rotate the 3D object to make it normal? Like, rotate the car to make engine side of a car as camera's front face.

2.How to place the 3D object on Plane Surface by facing the object towards the camera. Move the Phone camera to see the backside of the object.

I am using XCode 9.1 with iOS 11 and above, ARKIT

Answer (score 7):

[image]

To rotate the car node you can just adjust the eulerAngles until the car is facing the camera.

```
  node?.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(0,Float(degToRadians(degrees:180 )),Float(degToRadians(degrees: 90)))
```

rotated this van around to front facing.

[image]

eulerAngles are in radians, so a handy conversion to degrees:

```
public func degToRadians(degrees:Double) -> Double
 {
    return degrees * (M_PI / 180);
  }
```

You can also do the same rotation on the van node using an animation

```
    let rotate = SCNAction.rotateBy(x: CGFloat(degToRadians(degrees: -90)), y: 0, z: 0, duration: 1)
    node.runAction(rotate)
```

You can use SCNLookAtConstraint which follows the pointOfView along the negative z-axis of the parentNode.

So if the car’s negative z-axis is the camera facing the side doors... as you rotate the camera, around the car.... the car will swivel always maintaining that view.

```
  let constraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target:sceneView.pointOfView)
    constraint.isGimbalLockEnabled = true
    node.constraints = [constraint]
```

Inside Xcode, the screenshot below shows how you can change the rotation of the van using the euler angles (highlighted in red). The view should be “front” camera (also highlighted in red).  The animation can also be done inside Xcode via the animation panel, select “rotate Action” & drag into the Actions timeline in the bottom -middle

[image]

Comment: I have to make a sample project to place the 3D model on the plane or on-air depends upon the user selection (namely canPlaceOnPlane: Bool). While placing the object it has to face to the camera, so that I can move my phone to see another side of the model. Can you help me to write a code?? If possible can you share with the sample?

Comment: One more functionality if 3D animatable, tap on it to animate.

Comment: If you look at some of my recent answers, you can find several good code samples which do those things.

Comment: Please help me with samples. It will be useful to me to understand ARKit. I am a just 1-week old kid for AR. :(

Comment: In ARKit, placing a model at (0, 0, 0) often means the model is not in the center of the AR camera. Do you know how to make sure either (a) the AR camera points at (0, 0, 0) or (b) put the model in the center? Thanks for your help!

Comment: setting the camera.eulerAngles worked best for me:                                 
                                               `let camRotationX = camera?.eulerAngles.x
        let camRotationY = camera?.eulerAngles.y
       
        let x = Float(degToRadians(degrees: -90.0))-(Float(camRotationX!) * -1.0) // inverse of camera x
        node?.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(x, camRotationY!, 0)`

Comment: The rotation with animation is amazing. Thanks for this :)